# Google script to append multiple rows - select columns

Tags: google-apps-script

How can I append multiple rows from source sheet to destination sheet; select columns like A,C,H ?
source sheet columns A-Z, with multiple rows.
destination sheet - append rows from source sheet - select columns A, C and H only.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Transfer Data from one sheet to another selecting only columns A,C and H

```
function xferdata() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const ssh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const dsh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const vs = ssh.getRange(2,1,ssh.getLastRow() - 1, 8).getValues();
  let o = vs.map(([a,,c,,,,,h]) => [a,c,h]);
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(o));
  dsh.getRange(dsh.getLastRow() + 1,1,o.length,o[0].length).setValues(o);
}
```

Sheet0:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 | COL8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
| 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 |
| 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 |
| 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 |
| 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 |
| 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 |
| 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 |
| 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 |
| 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 |
| 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 |
| 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 |
| 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 |
| 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 |
| 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 |
| 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 |
| 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 |
| 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 |
| 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 | 27 |

Sheet1:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 8 |
| 2 | 4 | 9 |
| 3 | 5 | 10 |
| 4 | 6 | 11 |
| 5 | 7 | 12 |
| 6 | 8 | 13 |
| 7 | 9 | 14 |
| 8 | 10 | 15 |
| 9 | 11 | 16 |
| 10 | 12 | 17 |
| 11 | 13 | 18 |
| 12 | 14 | 19 |
| 13 | 15 | 20 |
| 14 | 16 | 21 |
| 15 | 17 | 22 |
| 16 | 18 | 23 |
| 17 | 19 | 24 |
| 18 | 20 | 25 |
| 19 | 21 | 26 |
| 20 | 22 | 27 |